# #1264 - Out of range value for column 'ano' at row 1

Tags: mysql

*Query*:

```
INSERT INTO veiculo(nome,modelo,placa,ano) 
VALUES('teste','testeModel','ASD5647',2012)
```

Campos:

```
nome   | varchar
modelo | varchar 
placa  | varchar
ano    | int
```

Erro reportado:

> #1264 - Out of range value for column 'ano' at row 1

Porque está com esse erro? Como resolver?

Comment: Confirme o tipo da coluna `ano`, pois não deve estar como `int`, coloque qual a DDL da sua tablea `veiculo`.

Answer (score 7):

<s>Não tem nada haver com "aspas simples", colunas tipo `int` não precisam de "aspas" nos valores passados</s>

Esse erro:

> 1264 - Out of range value for column

Indica que o valor inserido ultrapassou o limite definido, é provável que você não esteja inserindo `2012`, mas sim um valor totalmente diferente (ou seja o problema é no input dos dados) ou talvez você tenha usado algo como `DECIMAL(1,1)`.

Você pode alterar o tamanho com `ALTER TABLE` (se o tipo não for `int`):

```
ALTER TABLE veiculos MODIFY COLUMN ano INT(4);
```

Você também pode optar pelo tipo `DATE` ou `YEAR(4)`, não sei quais as vantagens terá com os tipo de colunas de data, mas talvez seja o uso das funções para cálculos.

Agora se o problema for realmente no ano, o problema é na origem dos dados.

Comment: não tinha lido bem o erro, está correta sua resposta :D

Comment: Acredito que o problema seja com o tipo que foi colocado para o campo `ano`. Se não me engano, o valor entre parenteses não está ligado quanto a quantidade de caracteres a ser armazenado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento te entendo, por isso pedi para ele confirmar, só comentei que o valor colocado em `INT(X)` não tem haver com o erro mencionado, veja http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07d273/1.

Comment: @Henrique é possivel mesmo, não havia me dado conta, revisei um pouco, mas realmente não tenho como saber aonde ocorreu o problema.